# Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type - NextJS 13.0.6 typescript 4.9.3

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm learning NextJS / TypeScript atm and encountered a type error. I have the following component

```
interface LayoutProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    title: string;
    keywords: string;
    description: string;
}

const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({ title, description, keywords, children }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>{title}</title>
                <meta name="description" content={description} />
                <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
            </Head>

            <Header />
            <div className={styles.container}>{children}</div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};
```

but when I use Layout to wrap any component, TS complains with the below:

```
interface HomePageProps {}

const HomePage: React.FC<HomePageProps> = ({}) => {
    return (
        // Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'LayoutProps'
        <Layout>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
        </Layout>
    );
};
```

I've tried passing defaultProps and made the children prop optional such as the below, but it didnt work.

```
interface LayoutProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode | null;
    title: string;
    keywords: string;
    description: string;
}

const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({ title = 'title', description = 'desc', keywords = 'kw', children = null }) => {...}
```

I'm stuck at this point and will appreciate any help / pointers. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) to `Layout`:

```
interface HomePageProps {}

const HomePage: React.FC<HomePageProps> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <Layout title="title" description="desc" keywords="kw">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Also, keep in mind that the `children` prop represents the children in your component call, so `<h1>Home Page</h1>` in this case

Comment: Thanks - it worked - I havent tried passing in the props because of the default values... Thank you so much again!